# NullPointerException в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android

Скачал пример с Google по `NavigationDrawer`, загрузил в AndroidStudio. Всё работает и на эмуляторе, и на телефоне. Разобрал код - вроде всё понятно.

Стал писать свой код (минимальная версия 4.0), но при выполнении следующего кода:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

При этом IDE не ругается, проект собирается и отправляется на эмулятор, сама иконка приложения вроде на месте (`mipmap`).

Порылся в Интернете - везде эта функция присутствует, у всех работает, эта тема не обсуждается, и поэтому не могу понять что я делаю не так.

Comment: Вы используете библиотеку AppCompat?

Comment: Две строки кода - маловато для определения причины проблемы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Проверьте, не используется ли в файле styles.xml тема с параметром .NoActionBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете `AppCompat` (то есть `Activity` наследуется от `AppCompatActivity`), то нужно вызывать не `getActionBar()`, а `getSupportActionBar()`.

Если же вы используете `Toolbar`, то сначала необходимо его установить в `actionbar`, а уже потом вызывать методы:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Либо:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Если вы не используете `AppCompat`.

Также вам стоит проверить, правильную ли тему указали для `Activity`.